# Find a pattern using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bunch of string lines with different formats. I want to find a pattern using regex in order to match specific lines. I have tried to figure it out myself up to some degree, using this: `\b([A-Z0-9]{2,})\b`. However I wasn't able to find the right pattern that will match only the lines 3, 6 and 8.Thank you.

`// DONE:
return Test;
TESTER
MessageBoxButtons.OK,
.GetConnectionString();
TOURNAMENT TRACKER
// Create
TEST 4 ME`

Comment: These lines are so special because they only consist of uppercase letters, numbers and spaces? Or are there other requirements (at least one word, only single space separators etc.)?

Comment: add case insensitive. What language BTW

Comment: It will match uppercase letters, numbers as @SebastianProske said.
Please specific more about your matching pattern, I recommend you to try this site http://regexr.com/

Comment: Right now a mere [`^[A-Z0-9 ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dmPbGF/1) will work. Or `^(?=.*\b[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b)[A-Z0-9 ]+$`. Or `^[A-Z0-9 ]*\b[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b[A-Z0-9 ]*$`

Comment: @MalteHartwig: There are no requirements, so a `.*` also works or does not work.

Comment: if you have a bigger dataset and the regex like in your example is this simple, then you can try using http://regex.inginf.units.it/ For this kind of regex problems it is optimal

Comment: @SebastianProske
I need to get back only the upper case lines that are not preceded by any character (/ or .). Also, the lines I need might have spaces between words and or digits.

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest. don't know how to :(. I am using C#

Comment: @ArAui. I've been trying [Regex101]: https://regex101.com for three days by now and I got tired.

Comment: @Greaka. thank you... I will look into it.

Comment: Gabriel, why did you put the `{2,}` into your regex? Do you have a minimum word length requirement? Or a word count minimum? Can letters and digit be mixed in words?

Comment: @MalteHartwig, I saw in http://regexr.com/ the ```{2,}``` stands for *Match for 2 or more preceding token*. Without it would not take the first upper case letters.
Again, I know there's something wrong with the Regex and couldn't find a better solution.
Also, there is no minimum word length requirment. And yes, letters and digits can be mixed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your solution also matched the first and fourth line. If you want to exclude the lines with characters other than those specified, you could look at the whole line instead of checking single words:

```
^[0-9A-Z]+(\s[0-9A-Z]+)*$
```

It will match lines consisting of white space separated words which contain numbers or uppercase letters.

Answer (score -1):

If you check the whole line you can use this

`^[A-Z0-9 ]+$`

Assuming case-sensitivity is set then this will match only uppercase characters, numbers and spaces from the start to the end of the line.

[See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/youi7z/1)

Comment: Note that this would also match `A1B2C3`. Not sure whether that's a concern, though.

Comment: @MalteHartwig True, but we will need more examples from the OP to be able to exclude other situations

Comment: Yes, just wanted to point it out to prevent surprises when using it. I am also still not sure what the `{2,}` in the original regex is for...

Comment: @MalteHartwig I think it was an attempt to exclude an uppercase followed by a lowercase but it also excludes all uppercase lines that start with char + space eg `A TESTER`